# Matplotlib: Mpl_toolkits, AxesGrid, ImageGrid and Anaconda: How do I get these functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have anaconda3 installed with matplotlib.

Only problem is, `mpl_toolkits` is not a recognized package.  I.e., the following code does not work:

```
import mpl_toolkits
```

I have searched high and low on google for some kind of package/download/makefile/etc. way to install `mpl_toolkits`, `AxesGrid`, `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1`, etc. in trying to do what is shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html).

I have run:

```
conda install mpl_toolkits
conda install axesgrid
conda install axes_grid1

...etc.
```

I have gone to the anaconda bin folder and run:

```
pip install ...
etc.
```

How do I get this package working with python (specifically anaconda)?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
conda activate # optional / use "source activate" in windows
conda install -c conda-forge basemap # use the -n flag for a particular environment
```

After that, you will get this folders:

```
/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/basemap-1.2.0-py3.7.egg-info
/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits
```

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong; the library `mpl_toolkits` should be in the anaconda environment.

The bazooka to knife-fight answer to this problem is to go to github, create a user name, search for "matplotlib" in the search bar, download matplotlib source code zip file from the matplotlib project...and run:

```
unzip matplotlib-master.zip
cd matplotlib-master
/your/path/to/anaconda3/bin/python3 setup.py install
```

Then, everything works. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This [bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4546/) suggests there may be something wrong with your installation due to old versions of packages (specifically basemap).

If you have git installed you can install `mpl_toolkits` with the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib
cd matplotlib
pip install -e .
```

Or download the latest zip from [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/archive/master.zip), unzip and use the same `pip install -e .` command in the resulting folder.